# Can `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` be updated with non-default configuration file values?

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, configurationmanager

I am trying to access a set of connection strings from an arbitrary configuration file provided *at runtime* by way of the [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings) static property. Application code expects the connection string to be in this collection and I need to provide a new value without editing the default configuration file.

I have determined that I can use [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration) to load connection strings from an arbitrary configuration file by using [`System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.configuration.execonfigurationfilemap), e.g.:

```
using System.Configuration;

var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap{ExeConfigFilename = 'some.config'}, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.RefreshSection(config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.SectionName);
```

In this context, I'd expect to be able to access the connection strings loaded from `some.config` from the static [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings) property but this seems to hold only what was available in the application configuration defaults.

Is it possible to mask or copy into the default configuration to update the value of the static `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` property? Alternatively, is any way to redefine the default configuration to a new configuration file *defined at runtime*, hopefully leading to the desired end result?

Comment: Right after this -  `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration` - check the `HasFile` property of `config`. Sometimes it will do evil stuff like *not* throw an exception even though it didn't load the file. It will give you a `Configuration` object that doesn't contain what's in your file.

Comment: Yup, `HasFile` property is `true` and `FilePath` is the non-default configuration file with my connection strings.

Comment: Can't you change the design of the application, to use a specialized service for your connections, connection manager or configuration service or something.

Comment: Sure, but I _know_ I can do that. I'm asking this question to see if there are any configuration tricks with which I'm unfamiliar that would work in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The `ConnectionStrings` and `AppSettings` properties of `ConfigurationManager` are just for convenience to read from the default configuration. You can load other configurations, but you can't change the behavior of those methods.

If this `Configuration` is properly loaded:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
    new ExeConfigurationFileMap{ExeConfigFilename = 'some.config'}.
        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Then you can get the connection string from there.

```
var connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["connectionName"]
    .ConnectionString;
```

A part of the answer is not to use `ConfigurationManager` or `Configuration` from deep within your classes. You can either use dependency injection, or, worst case scenario, create your own static class to use instead of `ConfigurationManager`. But this is a perfect example of why you don't want a class accessing this directly, because you can't change its behavior.

Comment: I don't think that's what he's after. He wants to map `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` to point to something more dynamic, set at runtime, at least that's what I'm reading.

Comment: If I get an opportunity to change this code, knowing what I do know about .NET configuration, I will remove the dependency on ConfigurationManager's static collections. For now, I'm exploring alternatives that exist for code as is.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting reflection workaround I [discovered](https://github.com/beefarino/powershell-app-domain-config/blob/master/AppDomainConfig/AppDomainConfig.psm1#L33) allows changing the non-public [System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection).bReadOnly property of [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings) by using reflection:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

var connectionString = "...";
var connectionStringSetting = new ConnectionStringSettings("OrionDB", connectionString);
var field = ConfigurationElementCollection.GetField("bReadOnly",
    Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var connectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
field.SetValue(connectionStrings, false);
connectionStrings.Add(connectionStringSetting);
```

This gave me the desired behaviour while not necessarily the intended use of the static `ConfigurationManager` properties.